# Why is my BLE Notification callback never called on Windows 8

Tags: windows, bluetooth, callback, notifications, gatt

I have a Bluetooth LE device with custom characteristics that send notifications to an android device just fine.

On Windows 8.1 however the notifications are not received. I can open a connection to the device using `CreateFile()`, enable notifications using `BluetoothGattSetDEscriptorValue()` and register a callback function using `BluetoothGattRegisterEvent()` without problems. However the used callback function is never called unless i continuously set a Characteristic value manually to keep the connection alive using something like this:

```
while(1){
    Sleep(1000);

    // Write characteristic using BLuetoothGattSetCharacteristicValue()
}
```

Is it supposed to work like this? How can i get the callback to be called when notifications are enabled without having to manually initiate the connection?

Comment: Another day without succes, i thought maybe it was because a console application does not have a message loop so i tried using a GUI application with the same result... 

I am starting to think that this is not posible using the bluetooth low energy functions described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Are you sure you enabled it the right way? Can you post the code calling `BluetoothGattSetDEscriptorValue`?

Comment: Super late but whatever.... The problem was caused by running windows in a virtual machine.